# Signal a Thread in boost to continue

Tags: boost

Is there any function in boost which can a thread wait on it until some special signal activates the thread for continuing? I don't like to use the `while(true) { if(event happend) break; }`, because the while is always running but I am looking for a function which blocks the thread until some signal or some events happen in the application. For example, something like this:

```
void thread(){

   while(true) {
        // Wait For Signal(s);

        // do your task
   }
}
```

Comment: This is precisely what [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) are for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK! so, if I call `mutex.lock()`, it will block the thread until the `mutex` is getting `unlock` by other threads?

Comment: Yes, but with condition variables, you only ever hold the mutex for a split second.

Comment: So, if unlocking takes more than 1 sec like 5 sec, I cannot use the `lock`?

Comment: That's why I'm saying you should use condition variables. The lock is only ever held for a split second. The long-term wait is done on the condition variable.